# Angular2- Promise is requiring array notation when accessing properties

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a component that is receiving data from a promise. The function looks like the following:

```
renderForm(selectedDate) {
  this._massEmpService.fetchTransitionFields(selectedDate)
    .then(results => {
      this.segments = results['segments']['options'];
      this.budgetMarkets = results['markets']['options'];
      this.roles = results['roles']['options'];
      this.languages = results['languages']['options'];
      this.incentivePlans = results['incentivePlans']['options'];
      this.hierarchy = results['hierarchy']['options'];
      this.fieldsLoaded = true;
      this.createForm(selectedDate);
    });
}
```

It is assigning the data to interfaces and those declarations are then used later on to populate dropdown menus.

My service call for the promise is:

```
fetchTransitionFields(effectiveStartDate) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this._http.post(this.baseUrl + '/fetchTransitionFields', { "effectiveStartDate": effectiveStartDate }, { "headers": this.headers })
            .map((result: Response) => result.json())
            .subscribe((results) => resolve(results.data));
    });
};
```

Whats bothering me is that I had to use bracket notation to access the properties from the promise. When I try and do `results.segments.options` i receive an error of `[ts] Property 'segment' does not exist on type '{}'.`.

Have I done something incorrectly that is forcing this? If its "normal" then all is good but its like the only place in the app that is using this style to access variables and it keeps catching my eye.

Comment: What if you specify a type for `results`? Either `any` or an interface which contains all the fields you access.

Comment: @E.Sundin - Where would you typecast this? I tried placing it after results `.then(results<any> => {` but typescript didn't like that.

Comment: It's generally called "bracket notation" not "array notation". And typecasts come before the thing your typing (`<any>results`).

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Thanks for correcting that, I knew it didnt sound right :). When I tried this in front as suggested, typescript just says that it can't find `results`.